# confusion regarding python and python3 command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an application which I am trying to make platform-independent with Python.

I have Python 3.x installed in all 3 OS-(Mac,Win10,Ubuntu)

I have a python script batch.py that calls other python scripts from within itself like this:

```
import os
import argparse
import shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--infolder", default="./pdfs", 
        help="Input folder with PDFs. Default: ./pdfs")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    infolder =args.infolder
    # Watermarking process    
    watermark_outfolder = tmp+'/pdfs_watermarked'
    if not os.path.exists(watermark_outfolder):
        os.makedirs(watermark_outfolder)
    else:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(watermark_outfolder):
            for f in files:
                os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
            for d in dirs:
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))
    watermark_command = 'python watermark.py --in '+infolder
    os.system(watermark_command)
```

The problem I am having is in Linux, the scripts don't run when I am using `os.system('python ...` it works only when I run as `os.system('python3 ...`.
On the other hand when I am running it in Win10, it works with python but not with python3.
I tried to put a check for the python version:

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        watermark_command = 'python watermark.py --in '+infolder
    else:
        watermark_command = 'python3 watermark.py --in '+infolder
    os.system(watermark_command)
```

Doing this doesn't help, it doesn't run in Win10

Comment: I think it's an alias problem, soneone actually using linux could confirm this. One easy fix is to setup the alias python to redirect to python3. On macOS I had to do so in the .zshrc file. I believe you have the same problem on macOS but you don't spot it as the command python3 is linked to python 3 and the command python is linked to python 2 (default install on macOS). Example in my .zshrc file: alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Script doesn't run. Can you elaborate more with the error trace or something? Also,  is the script `watermark.py` also platform dependent by any chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

two things:

(1) **don't use `os.system`** unless you want to get shell injected (prefer `subprocess.call` for example)

imagine if your `infolder` was named `'; touch pwnd'` (or something more nefarious!)

(2) **use `sys.executable`** in place of `python` or `python3`.  [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) refers to the executable you're running with

putting that all together, you'd have something like this:

```py
subprocess.call((sys.executable, 'watermark.py', '--in', infolder))
```

Comment: (2) assumes the first script is executed by python 3. This should be checked beforehand.